# Your best library for create GUI with Python (PyQt, PyGTK, wxPython, IronPython, etc)

Tags: python, windows, qt, gtk, pyqt

In your opinion, what is the best way to create gui in Windows with python ?

Do you recommend PyQt for windows?

Comment: They all work. I like PyQt4.

Comment: I like wx ... but basically what blender said

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the best and most documented is probably `PyQT`, but it depends on what you are developing. PyGTK has a really linuxy design. PyQT has one disadvantage that when compiled it is a really large file.

Advantages of Each:

**PyQt**

- Great support for signals and slots ([Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html))
- Great for model and view programming ([Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html))
- Has a great designer (`QtDesigner`)
- Cross platform Support
- Great support for both `c++` and `python`
- Third party plugins and development tools (e.g. `PyQWT`, networking, etc.) [Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/)

**PyGTK**

- Really nice Linux design
- Good documentation ([docs](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/))
- Well to do design tools ([Stetic](http://www.mono-project.com/Stetic), Glade)
- Supposedly great support for internationalized text
- Strong graphical element platform ([GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/))

**wxPython**

- Probably the best multiplatform support
- Well [documented for both `python` and `c++`](http://wxpython.org/onlinedocs.php)

But it all comes down to the design and the development style that you prefer. I recommend you pick one and just stick with it. For windows, its probably best to use `PyQt4` because of flexibility in design, code, and performance.

Comment: and about wxPython? does it have a great documentation?

Comment: Yes, it has great documentation, docs here http://wxpython.org/onlinedocs.php

Comment: `PyQT5` is rather new, I do know that you need a commercial license on `Qt5`. But i cannot seem to find `pyqt5` docs, you can try to use the `qt5` docs here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/index.html

Comment: wxPython does not have the best multi platform support. It doesn't even compile on Mac platforms. PyQt has the best multi-platform support. You can also go with PySide for the open source version of PyQt if you are worried about licensing.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer PyQt, there is some examples in the pyqt release directory, you can try it out. I think the effect is really cool.
I  haven't tried other library so i could not compare PyQt with others . As I am familiar with Qt, the coding experience is very easy if you switch Qt to PyQt.